# How to scan barcode using Appium?

Tags: c#, appium, mobile-automation

I'm looking for approach/solution on how to scan a bar code using Appium. Is it possible through emulators? or do I need real device for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

**Barcode scan using Appium** :

- This is one of the limitation of Automation I would say to automate scenarios with scanner or camera
- Simply because it has some infrastructure & application related challenges

**Possible work around [but not best practice]** :

- If performing tap on button [on mobile + from targeted app i.e. app which we are automating using appium] leads to open camera instead of redirecting user on diff application then we can think about some work around
- We can automate barcode scanner if we have provision in targeted application to fetch barcode from gallery/mobile images instead of actual scan. This might be a relative close match
- If we have only option to open inapp camera into targeted application, then we should give a rough try by keeping phone in such a way that when camera gets open and functional then barcode should have placed in front & in ideal position of scan
- Go for those work around when you do not have any other option & this is blocking you